# Is there a way to miniaturize cell-phone power adapter

Tags: power-supply, ac, dc

Is there a way to miniaturize a cell-phone power adapter to be not bigger than 1-3 cubic centimeters? Is there a way to do so by using more expensive parts or something like that?

I'm talking about usual cell-phone power adapters that transform 110 AC to 5V 1 A DC.

What are the limitation if it is not possible?

Comment: I assume you meant 1 A (one Amp) where you wrote 1AM. I edited it; if you didn't mean that please fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to miniaturize a cell-phone power adapter to be not bigger than 1-3 cubic centimeters? ... -> 110 AC to 5V 1 A DC.

Apart from the mechanical and connector issues, yes, it is possible to make the devices smaller.

Will it be expensive? oh yes!
 For a space mission this is a "just do it" requirement.
 For a consumer device, if you have to ask the price you can't afford one.
 [But, if you order 10,000 and pay in advance, I'll happily provide them for a few hundred dollars each].

The single most obvious method is to increase the frequency used by the SMPS (switched mode power supply. At present typical modern devices use frequencies from high 100's of kHz to low MHz range. By increasing rhe frequency to 10's of Mhz the inductances needed in transformers become utterly minimal and inductor size is a non issue.

You are then faced with actually making a device work efficiently at these frequencies and accommodating the electronics required in the available volume.

Making it work is "just a matter of engineering" [tm] :-). ie given enough $ you can provide devices capable of minimal switching losses at far higher frequencies. Synchronous rectification and resonant techniques and ... .

Component size is also not a major issue. One IC of minimal size, a few power devices (MOSFETS probably for switching an rectification) with the inductors already a non issue size wise. Noise filtering is at the multi MHz range so also small.

For 5V, 1A = 5W output and say even only 80% efficient
overall heat dissipation required =  5W x 0.2/0.8
 = 1.25W
 = acceptable for a device of that size given the right outer housing.

At 90% you need 550 mW heat dissipation.

Answer (score 4):

Not that I have ever seen. The Apple iPhone charge. 110 AC to 5 V 0.5 A DC. 1 cubic in.
For your 1 A requirement, see the iPad charger. It does at least 1 A. 3 cubic in. Even the iPhone one, as The Photon pointed out, about 16 x bigger than 1 cu cm and 5x than 3 cu cm.

As noted in [Ken Shrriff's blog](http://www.arcfn.com/2012/05/apple-iphone-charger-teardown-quality.html), the key steps to a good small charger are

1. Rectifying the input.
2. Chopping it (that was the part that was new to me).
3. Flyback transformer to get a lower voltage.
4. AC to DC conversion.

Comment: 1 cm^3 << 1 in^3. OP is asking for something that's just about smaller than the actual prongs needed to plug it into the wall.

Comment: So, is there a way to find smaller capacitors, switching transistor, and flyback transformer with the same working parameters to build a smaller version of the Apple charger?